# Could not find Chrome (ver. ######) in Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to generate PDFs according to mobile user data. So I have written a `firebase function` to access by the mobile applications. In the Firebase Function, I am using `puppeteer` to generate PDF from HTML. But the `puppeteer` continuously throws an error `Could not find Chrome (ver. ######)`.  `puppeteer` version `^19.3.8` and `node` version `16`. So my code is the following and I am calling following function in my Firebase Function:

```
async function generatePDF(htmlContent: string): Promise<Buffer> {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: 'new',
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
 });
 functions.logger.log('browser.version()', await browser.version());

 const page = await browser.newPage();

 await page.setContent(htmlContent, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

 const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({format: 'A4'});

 await browser.close();

 return pdfBuffer;
}
```

I thought to set up `.puppeteerrc.cjs` but afterward Firebase Function got huge in size and Firebase Function threw an error.

To overcome these problems, I have modified the function code as follow:

```
async function generatePDF(htmlContent: string): Promise<Buffer> {
   // Added this line
   await puppeteer
     .createBrowserFetcher()
     .download(puppeteer.PUPPETEER_REVISIONS.chromium);

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: 'new',
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  });

  functions.logger.log('browser.version()', await browser.version());

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setContent(htmlContent, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

  const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close();

  return pdfBuffer;
}
```

Then started to work but each and every time `chromium` got downloaded and took more memory. More importantly, it takes more time for each execution. So is there any other solution use with the Firebase function?